# vim shortcut keys for maximizing and minimizing shortcut keys

Tags: vim, shortcut

I m looking for a way to maximize and minimize split screen windows. I knew  about the shortcut keys but forget them. Any split screen tips are appreciated .

Answer (score 6):

To minimise the height of a split:

- Normal mode: `z0<CR>`
- Command mode: `:resize 0`

To maximise the height:

- Normal mode: `z999<CR>` or `<c-w>_`
- Command mode: `:resize 999`

These could of course be mapped to more convenient shortcuts if necessary.

You could also try so-called "Rolodex" mode, which always maximises the height of the active split:

```
:set winheight=999
```